# How to use a jinja variable inside of a quoted Html attribute?

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I want to iterate through events and entries replacing the indexes in the id="" and name='' attributes in the html form fields inside of the jinja template.

Something like this:

```html
{% for e in events %} 
    <td><input id="events-{{ index1 }}-entries-{{ index2 }}" 
        name="events-{{ index1 }}-entries" type="checkbox" 
        value="1"></td>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't figure out how to escape the quotes of the attributes so that the variable is inserted in the quoted text.

I've tried to escape the quotes, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could try to use string concatenation and put the "events-" and "-entries" inside the curlybraces. For example:

`{{ "Hello " ~ name ~ "!" }}` when `name` is assigned to the string 'John'  would return "Hello John!"

You can read more about Jinja string concatenation in the [official documentation.](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding my working solution from HTML as I spent a full day hunting for it in case it helps someone.

This html is passed back its prefill data and I could not get access to the variables I needed from that dict in the Jinja2 for loop

`render_template('home.html', prefill_data=request.form)`

The real key here was this trick to get a variable in as key in string format
`prefill_data["player{}name".format(n)]`

And these curly braces to access value as string
`"{{ prefill_data["player{}name".format(n)]}}"`

```
{% if nplayer_form is not defined %}
    {% set nplayer_form = 4 %}
{% endif %}   

{% if session['additional_players'] %}
    {% set nplayer_form = nplayer_form + session['additional_players'] %}
{% endif %}


{% for i in range(nplayer_form) %}
    {% set n = i+1 %}
    <tr id="Row{{ n }}">
    <td>
    <label for="player{{ n }}name_input" name="player{{ n }}name_input_label"></label>
    <input type="text" name="player{{n}}name" id = "player{{n}}name_input" {% if prefill_data %} value="{{ prefill_data["player{}name".format(n)]}}"{% endif %}/>
    </td>

    <td>
    <label for="player{{n}}strength_id" name="player{{n}}strength"></label>
    <select name="player{{n}}strength" id="player{{n}}strength_id"> 
        <option value="1" {% if prefill_data %}{% if ((prefill_data["player{}strength".format(n)]) == "1") %} selected {% endif %}{% endif %}>Beginner</option>
        <option value="2" {% if prefill_data %}{% if ((prefill_data["player{}strength".format(n)]) == "2") %} selected {% endif %}{% endif %}>Intermediate</option>
        <option value="3" {% if prefill_data %}{% if ((prefill_data["player{}strength".format(n)]) == "3") %} selected {% endif %}{% endif %}>Advanced</option>                 
    </select>
    </td>
    
    <td>
    <label for="p{{n}}checkbox_id" name="p{{n}}checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" id="p{{n}}checkbox_id" name="p{{n}}checkbox" {% if prefill_data %} {% if (prefill_data["p{}checkbox".format(n)] =="on") %} checked {% endif %} {% endif %} />
    </label>
    </td>
 
    </tr>
    
{% endfor %}
```